# how to change redirect when login in theme my login wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I want to  change redirect when login in theme my login wordpress 
now when login yet, it will go to profile page but I don't want this. I want to change it to go to my homepage. 
I find code in themed-profiles.php . I think I much edit code in line 166 but how to edit? please help.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    //$redirect_to = get_option('shop-subearphone2');
                    $redirect_to = Theme_My_Login::get_page_link( 'profile' );
                    wp_redirect( $redirect_to );

                    exit;
```

Comment: https://vrajeshdave.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/login-to-perticular-template-if-login-failed/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it sorted. I just removed the redirection module from used a WordPress function and put `function.php`

```
function redirect_to_profile() {
    $who = strtolower(sanitize_user($_POST['log']));
    $redirect_to = get_option('home') . '/profile?' . $who;
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_profile');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for general question in wordpress you can view my blog Site https://valabhavesh.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'init', 'blockusers_init' );
    function blockusers_init() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) &&
    ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); // set here your redirection Url
    exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
add_action('init','redirect');

function redirect(){
global $pagetheme;
if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagetheme) {
wp_redirect('http://yourpage.com/'); // instead of yourpage.php to what page you want to redirect
}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a custom file in the /wp-content/plugins folder which must be called 'theme-my-login-custom.php' and in there I just put:

```
<?php
function custom_redirect() {
  return "/member";
}
add_filter( 'tml_redirect_url', 'custom_redirect' );
?>
```

This did the job for me using TML 6.4.5